# How to create layout using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

how to create layout with header, main content and footer in separately files?

In *Site.Master* there is a Menu, main content and footer together and I want to separate them.
I've created new Web Form with Master Page (Menu.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Menu.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Menu" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="menu" runat="server">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

and I'm trying to include it in *Site.Master*:

```
<form runat="server">
    <!-- Menu -->
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="menu" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </div>
</form>
```

but it won't render. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the `MasterPageFile` in your `Menu.ascx` shouldn't be there. The menu is like a partial view, it shouldn't have masterpage. However, I would chose different approach.

> Menu

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Menu.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.Menu" %>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">Application name</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I've done on the Menu page: I removed the `MasterPageFile` attribute of the menu, because the menu isn't a whole page but a part of one (like partial view in MVC). Also, removed the `<asp:Content>` tag because you don't want the menu to be rendered in the main of your `Site.Master`.

> Site.Master

Include this line on the top of the `Site.Master`

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Menu" TagName="Menu" Src="the path to your Menu.ascx" %>
```

Change the value of the `Src` attribute with the path to your `Menu.Ascx` page.

Now you can render your `Menu.ascx` page wherever you want in your `Site.Master` like that:

```
<Menu:Menu runat="server" />
```

I am not 100% sure it will work because I haven't tested it. If something's wrong comment below. I will help you.

Comment: I cannot use it in this way because menu.aspx does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'. I got an error: `Parser Error Message: Type 'ASP.menu_aspx' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.` Error line: `Line 2:  <%@ Register TagPrefix="Menu" TagName="Menu" Src="Menu.aspx" %>`

Comment: On the top of `menu.aspx` write `Control` instead of `Page`

Comment: I've converted aspx to ascx and I've also removed ID from menu control so you can edit your answer. Thanks

Comment: The ID from menu control is just in case you want to manipulate it in the back-end of Site.Master.